# App Center Test task: uitest (Xamarin UI Test) DevOps AppCenterTest@1

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center-test

I try to test a Xamarin App, works on localhost, doesn't seems to work on Azure DevOps.

**Error Android:**

```
 Preparing tests... failed.
Error: Failed to prepare UI Test artifacts using command "test-cloud.exe prepare" with error message:
There was an unknown error preparing test artifacts, please try again. If you can't work out how to fix this issue, please contact support.
```

```
- task: AppCenterTest@1
  displayName: 'App Test Android'
  inputs:
    appFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app.apk'
    artifactsDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    uitestToolsDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    frameworkOption: uitest
    serverEndpoint: 'androidEndPoint'
    appSlug: 'MyOrg/Android'
    uiTestBuildDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    debug: true
    enablePrepare: true
    devices: bc141325
    userDefinedLocale: 'de_DE'
    series: 'master'
```

**Error iOs:**

```
Response status code: 400
Body: {"message":"The .ipa file does not seem to be linked with Calabash framework."}
Starting test run... failed.
Error: The .ipa file does not seem to be linked with Calabash framework.
```

```
    - task: AppCenterTest@1
      displayName: 'App Test Mac'
      inputs:
       appFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/iosapp.ipa'
       artifactsDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AppCenterTest'
       frameworkOption: uitest
       serverEndpoint: 'iosappEndPoint'
       uitestToolsDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
       appSlug: 'MyOrg/iosapp'
       devices: 'MyOrg/test'
       enablePrepare: true
       userDefinedLocale: 'de_DE'
       showDebugOutput: true
       uiTestBuildDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
       series: 'master'
```

Why Calabash?

I also installed this and running on a macOS-latest host:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.14.2'
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'npm install -g appcenter-cli'
  inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: | 
        npm i -D webpack@latest
        npm install -g appcenter-cli
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Calabash is what Xamarin.UITest uses internally. The issue is that the step cannot seem to find Xamarin.UITest linked in your Application. Make sure to have a call to `Xamarin.Calabash.Start();` in your code.

Comment: thanks, I forgot this. The error now is "##[error]Error: Input required: framework" But its set in the yaml.